# How to run two commands simultaneously?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have two videos and need to play them (by mplayer) exactly at the same time. How to do that ?

Comment: Write a bash script?

Comment: can be, but how it looks like ?

Comment: Just put the shebang line followed by the two commands I beleive

Comment: What do you mean by playing at the same time? Do you mean, on the same screen, using the same instance of mplayer, on multiple screens, on multiple workspaces, on different computers on the network?,.... Or do you mean to merge two videos into a single video?

Comment: I mean two instances of mplayer (two windows) simply. I want to see the difference beetween that videos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start up multiple background tasks. This means that the second one does not need to wait for the first one to finish loading. The `&` tell the command to run in the background.

From the command-line: In the first one, the number of `.` (dots) equals the number of instances.

```
set "/my/vid/path.mp4"   
for i in . . ;do (mplayer "$1" &) ;done
```

*or*

```
set "/my/vid/path.mp4"; ( 
mplayer "$1" &
mplayer "$1" & )
```

*or*

```
( mplayer "/my/vid/path.mp4" &
  mplayer "/my/vid/path.mp4" & )
```

Or in a script called by `play-two "/my/vid/path.mp4"`

```
#!/bin/bash
mplayer "$1" &
mplayer "$1" &
```

Comment: I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'`

Comment: You can put the commands on different lines.   It is working fine for me..  I have just loaded 2x 4GB matroska vids and the synchronization is perfect... It is an interesing effect, for some clips :)

Answer (score 13):

[GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

In your particular case:

```
parallel  mplayer ::: file1.avi file2.avi
```